# Dynamics CRM 2016 PluginProfiler System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm having problems debugging my assembly using the PluginProfiler supplied with the PluginRegistrationTool. Once I mark the step as profiling and trigger it (Create an account) it shows the following error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: 

System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected Exception in the Plug-in ProfilerDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>CallStack</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerBase`1.InitializeProfiler(Dictionary`2 services, T operationContext, ProfilerPluginContext&amp; context)
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxAppDomainHelper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;Execute&gt;b__1()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxAppDomainHelper.Execute(IOrganizationServiceFactory organizationServiceFactory, Dictionary`2 sandboxServices, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, IPluginExecutionContext requestContext, Boolean enablePluginStackTrace, Boolean chaosFailAppDomain)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxAppDomainHelper.Execute(IOrganizationServiceFactory organizationServiceFactory, Dictionary`2 sandboxServices, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, IPluginExecutionContext requestContext, Boolean enablePluginStackTrace, Boolean chaosFailAppDomain)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxWorker.Execute(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxPluginExecutionContext requestContext, Guid pluginAssemblyId, Int32 sourceHash, String assemblyName, Guid pluginTypeId, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, SandboxRequestCounter&amp; workerCounter, Boolean returnTraceInfo)</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">3</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>SubErrorCode</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">-2146233088</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Unexpected Exception in the Plug-in Profiler</Message>
  <Timestamp>2017-09-20T11:11:16.7252255Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[PluginProfiler.Plugins: PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin]
[585cb523-f29d-e711-81b0-000d3a22c45c: XXXXXXXX.Xrm.Plugins.BasicEntryPoints.GenericPlugin: Create of account (Profiler)]

An exception occurred during the initialization of the Plug-in Profiler.
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerationOptions.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownTypesProvider.get_KnownOrganizationRequestResponseTypes()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownTypesResolver.ResolveName(String typeName, String typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.ResolveDataContractFromDataContractResolver(XmlQualifiedName typeName, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.ResolveDataContractFromKnownTypes(String typeName, String typeNs, DataContract memberTypeContract, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.IsKnownType(DataContract dataContract, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.IsKnownType(DataContract dataContract, Dictionary`2 knownDataContracts, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeDataContractResolver.TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, XmlDictionaryString&amp; typeName, XmlDictionaryString&amp; typeNamespace)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownTypesResolver.TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, XmlDictionaryString&amp; typeName, XmlDictionaryString&amp; typeNamespace)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.ResolveType(Type objectType, Type declaredType, XmlDictionaryString&amp; typeName, XmlDictionaryString&amp; typeNamespace)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteTypeInfo(XmlWriterDelegator writer, DataContract contract, DataContract declaredContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxUtility.SerializeDataContract[T](T dataContract, Assembly proxyTypesAssembly)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper.ExecuteInternal(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper.RetrieveInternal(String entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper.Retrieve(String entityName, Guid entityId, ColumnSet columnSet)
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshAssembly(IOrganizationService service, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext context)
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshPluginInitializationContext(IOrganizationServiceFactory factory, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext currentContext)
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerBase`1.InitializeProfiler(Dictionary`2 services, T operationContext, ProfilerPluginContext&amp; context)



</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

I'm using `StructureMap` as IoC container and `StructureMap.AutoFactory`, which requires `Castle.Core`. I'm using ILMerge to merge all assemblies into a single on. I'm using the following arguments to execute ILMerge:

```
/target:library
/out:"$outPath"
/log:"$logFile"
/keyfile:"${keyFile}"
/copyattrs
/wildcards
/targetplatform:"v4,${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2"
```

and the following assemblies (left out my dlls):

```
"${targetDir}StructureMap.dll"
"${targetDir}StructureMap.AutoFactory.dll"
"${targetDir}Castle.Core.dll"
```

I'm really out of ideas and it would be great if someone finds the time to help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As per [this article](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/xrmcenter/archive/2016/04/06/key-notes-of-ms-crm-plugin-technology-for-beginners) the Sandboxed environment in which plugins run prohibits the use of Reflection to access internal members. I'm not familiar with dynamics proxying per se, but it looks like creating types on the fly and potentially using reflection in the process may not be possible in the sandbox.

If you have an on-prem dev environment you could register the plugin outside the sandbox and see what happens.